# Set the maximum value of the group to each group id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This may be a stupid question and very easy but i am very distracted right now, and didn't find any solution.

I have a table like this:

```
ID | Value | Gr_Id | Gr_Value
------------------------------
a  |0      |1      |Null
b  |2      |2      |Null
c  |4      |2      |Null
d  |1      |3      |Null
e  |3      |4      |Null
f  |3      |4      |Null
g  |2      |5      |Null
h  |3      |5      |Null
```

Desired Output:

```
ID | Value | Gr_Id | Gr_Value
------------------------------
a  |0      |1      |0
b  |2      |2      |4
c  |4      |2      |4
d  |1      |3      |1
e  |3      |4      |3
f  |3      |4      |3
g  |2      |5      |3
h  |3      |5      |3
```

So i want to update the group value and set the maximum value of the group_id.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem:

```
SELECT ID, Value, Gr_Id, (
           SELECT MAX(Value)
           FROM tableName t2 
           WHERE t1.Gr_Id = t2.Gr_Id
) as Gr_Value
FROM tableName t1
```

Try it; hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Using `OUTER APPLY` you can do this

```
SELECT ID,Value,Gr_Id,M.Gr_Value
FROM URTable
OUTER APPLY
(
 SELECT MAX (Value) as Gr_Value
 FROM URTable tmp
 WHERE tmp.Gr_Id=URTable.Gr_Id
)M
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using common table expression:

```
CREATE TABLE #t
(ID char,Value int, Gr_Id int, gr_value int)

INSERT #t(id, value, gr_id) 
values
('a',0,1),('b',2,2),('c',4,2),('d',1,3),
('e',3,4),('f',3,4),('g',2,5),('h',3,5)

;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT 
    gr_value, 
    max(value) over(partition by gr_id) max_gr_value
  FROM #t
)
UPDATE CTE SET gr_value = max_gr_value

SELECT * FROM #t
```

Result:

```
ID   Value  Gr_Id  Gr_value
a    0      1      0
b    2      2      4
c    4      2      4
d    1      3      1
e    3      4      3
f    3      4      3
g    2      5      3
h    3      5      3
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
UPDATE MyTable --whatever your table is called
SET Gr_Value = MaxValues.Value
FROM MyTable
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Gr_Id, MAX(Value) AS Value
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY Gr_Id) AS MaxValues ON MaxValues.Gr_Id = MyTable.Gr_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Gtable(ID varchar, Value int , Gr_Id int, Gr_Value int)
Insert into Gtable Values('a', 0, 1, null)
Insert into Gtable Values('b', 2, 2, null)
Insert into Gtable Values('c', 4, 2, null)
Insert into Gtable Values('d', 1, 3, null)
Insert into Gtable Values('e', 3, 4, null)
Insert into Gtable Values('f', 3, 4, null)
Insert into Gtable Values('g', 2, 5, null)
Insert into Gtable Values('h', 3, 5, null)

 select A.Id, A.Value, A.Gr_Id, C.maxV Gr_Value from Gtable A
JOIN 
    (   select A.Gr_Id, max(B.Value) maxV from
            ( select Distinct Gr_Id from Gtable ) A
                JOIN Gtable B On A.Gr_Id=B.Gr_Id 
                Group by A.Gr_Id
                ) C
                On A.Gr_Id=C.Gr_Id
```

---

```
Id  Value   Gr_Id   Gr_Value
a   0   1   0
b   2   2   4
c   4   2   4
d   1   3   1
e   3   4   3
f   3   4   3
g   2   5   3
h   3   5   3
```

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Gr_Value = t2.val
FROM tblGroup t1
JOIN (SELECT Gr_Id, MAX(Value) AS val FROM tblGroup GROUP By Gr_Id) t2
ON t1.Gr_Id = t2.Gr_Id;
```